# How to get all rows in a region that skips over a first region in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks that interact with each other:

1. Admin Doc - Pulls down data from an SSMS server
2. Calc Doc - One that will pull data from the first workbook and calculate certain fields

The way that the Admin Doc is set up as you can see from the attached image is that it will pull a subset of data based on inputting either an ID or SID into cells A1 or C1 respectively. Some things to note:

1. The amount of rows for both the first and seconds subsets will vary
2. The number of headers for the first, as well as the second subsets is static
3. The first subset will always populate beginning in Cell A2
4. The second subset will always populate a cell after the end of the first subset i.e. the first subset ends at A6 and so the second subset will skip a cell and then populate into the next cell, so in this example A7 is skipped and A8 is populated.

What I need to accomplish is to be able to only read the second subset of data. For instance, I know how to take into account all rows of data to the last filled in row i.e. total_rows = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row should give me all the rows in the first subset despite variation of data. How can I skip over the first subset of data and read the entirety of the second subset so that I can use the data within that second subset to map into my Calc Doc? Let me know if you need further clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headers are fixed:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim f As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Data") 'for example
Set f = ws.Columns(1).Find(what:="ID", after:=ws.Range("A2"), lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not f Is Nothing And f.Row > 2 Then 'allow for "not found" and wrapping back to row2
 
     Debug.Print f.CurrentRegion.Address 'second block of data
 
End If
```